# Check if a DataTables-element is currently filtered through search

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables

I have a situation where I need to figure out if a jQuery-DataTables is currently filtered through the search.

Is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the `value` of the search-input. But there are better solutions provided by the `DatatTables`-library.

To get the query of a global search you can use the `search()`-method without a parameter and compare the returned string:

```
let query = table.search();
console.log(query); // outputs a string
```

But there are other options to perform a search for data in DataTables, like the column-search. With the column-search you are able to perform a more complex search with individual queries for each column. These queries do not appear in the search-input and are also not returned by the `search()`-method of the DataTables-Object. To get the queries of the columns you can iterate over all columns and utilize the `search()`-method to read the current query-value:

```
let queries = [];
let columns = table.columns().indexes();
for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  queries.push(table.column(i).search());
}
console.log(queries); // outputs an array of strings
```

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let table = $('#example').DataTable();
  
  $('#get-queries').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // get and output global query
    let query_global = table.search();
    console.log('global query:');
    console.log(query_global);
    
    // get and output column queries
    let query_columns = [];
    let columns = table.columns().indexes();
    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
      query_columns.push(table.column(i).search());
    }
    console.log('column queries:');
    console.log(query_columns);
  });
  
  $('#custom-search-1').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // perform global query (and draw data)
    table.search('Alpha').draw();
  });
  
  $('#custom-search-2').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // perform different queries on columns
    table.columns(0).search('Alpha');
    table.columns(1).search('Test');
    // draw data
    table.draw();
  });

  $('#reset').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // reset global query
    table.search('');
    // reset column queries
    table.columns().search('');
    // draw data
    table.draw();
  });

});
```

```css
#get-queries {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}

#custom-search-1,
#custom-search-2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
}

#reset {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="get-queries">Get queries</button> / 
<button id="custom-search-1">Search global</button>
<button id="custom-search-2">Search in columns</button> / 
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

<hr>

<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Test-1</td><td>Test 1234</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test-3</td><td>I dont know!</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test-2</td><td>Another...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Alpha-1</td><td>Apple Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Alpha-2</td><td>Banana Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Alpha-3</td><td>Coconut</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Beta-1</td><td>Beta</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Beta-2</td><td>Not Alpha</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So helpful for column search. That made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a way to do it. Basically I am checking if the search input has a value.

```
if($('#myIdnameHere').find('input[type=search]').val() == ''){
    //then I know that it isn't filtered.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not always work.
If you set the filter manually (in my example column filter), it is saved internally but is not visible after you have left the page and returned.
My goal is to read it out internally and then write it back into the field so that it is visible to the user.